# How can I swap in a new value for a field in a mutable reference to a structure?

Tags: rust

I have a struct with a field:

```
struct A {
    field: SomeType,
}
```

Given a `&mut A`, how can I move the value of `field` and swap in a new value?

```
fn foo(a: &mut A) {
    let mut my_local_var = a.field;
    a.field = SomeType::new();

    // ...
    // do things with my_local_var
    // some operations may modify the NEW field's value as well.
}
```

The end goal would be the equivalent of a `get_and_set()` operation. I'm not worried about concurrency in this case.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Use [`std::mem::swap()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.swap.html).

```
fn foo(a: &mut A) {
    let mut my_local_var = SomeType::new();
    mem::swap(&mut a.field, &mut my_local_var);
}
```

Or [`std::mem::replace()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.replace.html).

```
fn foo(a: &mut A) {
    let mut my_local_var = mem::replace(&mut a.field, SomeType::new());
}
```

Comment: Or `let mut my_local_var = mem::replace(&mut a.field, SomeType::new());`. The two are precisely equivalent.

Answer (score 38):

If your type implements [`Default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/default/trait.Default.html), you can use [`std::mem::take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.take.html):

```rust
#[derive(Default)]
struct SomeType;

fn foo(a: &mut A) {
    let mut my_local_var = std::mem::take(&mut a.field);
}
```

If your field happens to be an `Option`, there's a specific method you can use — [`Option::take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.take):

```
struct A {
    field: Option<SomeType>,
}

fn foo(a: &mut A) {
    let old = a.field.take();
    // a.field is now None, old is whatever a.field used to be
}
```

The [implementation of `Option::take`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.42.0/src/libcore/option.rs#L876-L878) uses `mem::take`, just like the more generic answer above shows, but it is wrapped up nicely for you:

```rust
pub fn take(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
    mem::take(self)
}
```

See also:

- [Temporarily move out of borrowed content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29570781/155423)
- [Change enum variant while moving the field to the new variant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36557412/155423)