# "thread '<main>' has overflowed its stack" when constructing a large tree

Tags: rust

I implemented a tree struct:

```
use std::collections::VecDeque;
use std::rc::{Rc, Weak};
use std::cell::RefCell;

struct A {
    children: Option<VecDeque<Rc<RefCell<A>>>>
}

// I got thread '<main>' has overflowed its stack
fn main(){
    let mut tree_stack: VecDeque<Rc<RefCell<A>>> = VecDeque::new();

    // when num is 1000, everything works
    for i in 0..100000 {
        tree_stack.push_back(Rc::new(RefCell::new(A {children: None})));
    }

    println!("{:?}", "reach here means we are not out of mem");
    loop {
        if tree_stack.len() == 1 {break;}

        let mut new_tree_node = Rc::new(RefCell::new(A {children: None}));
        let mut tree_node_children: VecDeque<Rc<RefCell<A>>> = VecDeque::new();

        // combine last two nodes to one new node
        match tree_stack.pop_back() {
            Some(x) => {
                tree_node_children.push_front(x);
            },
            None => {}
        } 
        match tree_stack.pop_back() {
            Some(x) => {
                tree_node_children.push_front(x);
            },
            None => {}
        } 

        new_tree_node.borrow_mut().children = Some(tree_node_children);
        tree_stack.push_back(new_tree_node);
    }
}
```

[Playpen link](http://is.gd/0RF6SR)

But it crashes with

```
thread '<main>' has overflowed its stack
```

How do I fix that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  To get the best quality of answers, please review [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In this particular case, you should include your code inline, not just a link to it (links may die, and then future programmers can't benefit!). Don't just post all of your code though! Instead, construct a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to narrow down the problem and make it easier on answerers. You should only have one question, and be cautious about opinion questions ("best practice"), as they are out-of-scope for this site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem that you are experiencing is because you have a giant linked-list of nodes. When that list is dropped, the first element tries to free all the members of the struct first. That means that the second element does the same, and so on, until the end of the list. This means that you will have a call stack that is proportional to the number of elements in your list!

Here's a small reproduction:

```
struct A {
    children: Option<Box<A>>
}

fn main() {
    let mut list = A { children: None };

    for _ in 0..1_000_000 {
        list = A { children: Some(Box::new(list)) };
    }
}
```

And here's how you would fix it:

```
impl Drop for A {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        if let Some(mut child) = self.children.take() {
            while let Some(next) = child.children.take() {
                child = next;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code overrides the default recursive drop implementation with an iterative one. It rips the `children` out of the node, replacing it with a terminal item (`None`). It then allows the node to drop normally, but there will be no recursive calls.

The code is complicated a bit because we can't drop ourselves, so we need to do a little two-step dance to ignore the first item and then eat up all the children.

See also:

- [How can I swap in a new value for a field in a mutable reference to a structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27098694/155423)
- [How do I move out of a struct field that is an Option?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52031002/155423)

Comment: I'm having the same problem, with slightly different code. In your example reproduction I do not understand when the list is being dropped. Are you not just adding a sequence of chained nodes? why would it overflow the stack?

Comment: @Miguel the `list` variable is dropped at the end of its scope (the end of `main`). The stack overflows because the default `Drop` implementation of `A` calls the `Drop` implementation of `Option<Box<A>>` which calls the `Drop` implementation of `Box<A>` which calls the `Drop` implementation of `A` (and so on). Each function call adds to the stack depth.