# Temporarily move out of borrowed content

Tags: rust, ownership, borrow-checker

I'm tring to replace a value in a mutable borrow; moving part of it into the new value:

```
enum Foo<T> {
    Bar(T),
    Baz(T),
}

impl<T> Foo<T> {
    fn switch(&mut self) {
        *self = match self {
            &mut Foo::Bar(val) => Foo::Baz(val),
            &mut Foo::Baz(val) => Foo::Bar(val),
        }
    }
}
```

The code above doesn't work, and understandibly so, moving the value out of `self` breaks the integrity of it. But since that value is dropped immediately afterwards, I (if not the compiler) could guarantee it's safety.

Is there some way to achieve this? I feel like this is a job for unsafe code, but I'm not sure how that would work.

Comment: If you add a `Copy` bound to `T`, your code actually works, although I obviously don't know if you're ok with that restriction.

Answer (score 11):

[`mem::uninitialized`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.uninitialized.html) has been deprecated since Rust 1.39, replaced by [`MaybeUninit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html).

However, uninitialized data is not required here. Instead, you can use `ptr::read` to get the data referred to by `self`.

At this point, `tmp` has ownership of the data in the enum, but if we were to drop `self`, that data would attempt to be read by the destructor, causing memory unsafety.

We then perform our transformation and put the value back, restoring the safety of the type.

```
use std::ptr;

enum Foo<T> {
    Bar(T),
    Baz(T),
}

impl<T> Foo<T> {
    fn switch(&mut self) {
        // I copied this code from Stack Overflow without reading
        // the surrounding text that explains why this is safe.
        unsafe {
            let tmp = ptr::read(self);
    
            // Must not panic before we get to `ptr::write`

            let new = match tmp {
                Foo::Bar(val) => Foo::Baz(val),
                Foo::Baz(val) => Foo::Bar(val),
            };
    
            ptr::write(self, new);
        }
    }
}
```

More advanced versions of this code would **prevent** a panic from bubbling out of this code and instead cause the program to abort.

See also:

- [replace_with](https://crates.io/crates/replace_with), a crate that wraps this logic up.
- [take_mut](https://crates.io/crates/take_mut), a crate that wraps this logic up.
- [How can I change enum variant while moving the field to the new variant?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36557412/155423)
- [How can I swap in a new value for a field in a mutable reference to a structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27098694/155423)

Answer (score 7):

> The code above doesn't work, and understandibly so, moving the value
>   out of self breaks the integrity of it.

This is not exactly what happens here. For example, same thing with `self` would work nicely:

```
impl<T> Foo<T> {
    fn switch(self) {
        self = match self {
            Foo::Bar(val) => Foo::Baz(val),
            Foo::Baz(val) => Foo::Bar(val),
        }
    }
}
```

Rust is absolutely fine with partial and total moves. The problem here is that you do not own the value you're trying to move - you only have a mutable borrowed reference. You cannot move out of any reference, including mutable ones.

This is in fact one of the frequently requested features - a special kind of reference which would allow moving out of it. It would allow several kinds of useful patterns. You can find more [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/998) and [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/965).

In the meantime for some cases you can use [`std::mem::replace`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.replace.html) and [`std::mem::swap`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.swap.html). These functions allow you to "take" a value out of mutable reference, provided you give something in exchange.

Comment: It makes little sense for me to require the caller of the method to own `Foo`, when it is possible to implement it using only a `&mut`. Ownership shouldn't be required in this case, as the integrity of `self` can be guaranteed.

Comment: @azgult and that's exactly the reason why a lot of people request `&own`-like pointer (see the links to RFC and issue I provided) - because such thing in fact *do* require ownership (*only* owner can move values around).

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I figured out how to do it with a bit of `unsafe`ness and `std::mem`.

I replace `self` with an uninitialized temporary value. Since I now "own" what used to be `self`, I can safely move the value out of it and replace it:

```
use std::mem;

enum Foo<T> {
    Bar(T),
    Baz(T),
}

impl<T> Foo<T> {
    fn switch(&mut self) {
        // This is safe since we will overwrite it without ever reading it.
        let tmp = mem::replace(self, unsafe { mem::uninitialized() });
        // We absolutely must **never** panic while the uninitialized value is around!

        let new = match tmp {
            Foo::Bar(val) => Foo::Baz(val),
            Foo::Baz(val) => Foo::Bar(val),
        };

        let uninitialized = mem::replace(self, new);
        mem::forget(uninitialized);
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

Comment: This program will fail horribly if `T` has destructor. When you call `swap` you're replacing whatever is located at `self` with garbage. Then you reassign `*self`, and Rust will insert a call to destructor which would attempt to destroy the "old" value of `*self`, which is now garbage. For some reason [playpen](http://is.gd/uaIhEe) does not fail (but you can see double free there), but for me that program core dumps when I compile and run it locally.

Comment: [This](http://is.gd/yT03vG) program more clearly demonstrates when and how a destructor is called. If your program was safe, it would be called only once, but it is called twice - the first time being erroneous.

Comment: Good catch. I believe that the modified version which uses `std::ptr::write` should be safe however.

Comment: no it's not safe, now you are actually dropping uninitialized memory. You need to `mem::forget` the `tmp` variable after the `write` call

Comment: @oli_obk-ker I rewrote the answer based on these comments because it was being linked to; how does it look now?

Comment: @VladimirMatveev I rewrote the answer based on these comments because it was being linked to; how does it look now?

Comment: [`take`](https://docs.rs/take_mut/0.2.0/take_mut/fn.take.html) shows how to do this in a generic way, and also protects against unwinding (aborts instead).

Comment: Please note that, while edits avoid the obvious double free, this program still exihbits undefined behavior because it creates an unitialized value and sends it to a function. This is forbidden and can lead to miscompilations, **even for a function that ignores the value, like `mem::forget()`**. Run [this playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=91ecb17fa0b80ad133a0df43136d613a) with tools->miri to see UB explicitly identified by MIRI.