# Replace a struct member with a new value that uses the previous value

Tags: syntax, rust, move-semantics, unsafe

I have a struct which owns a boxed value of some trait type. The struct itself also implements the same trait. I would like to replace the value with a new instance of the same struct, which wraps it.

The following code, which does not compile, should make it more clear what I am trying to do:

```
trait T {}

struct S {
    t: Box<dyn T>,
}
impl T for S {}

impl S {
    fn new(t: Box<dyn T>) -> Self {
        Self { t }
    }

    fn wrap_t(&mut self) {
        self.t = Box::new(Self::new(self.t))
    }
}
```

This fails:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/lib.rs:14:37
   |
14 |         self.t = Box::new(Self::new(self.t))
   |                                     ^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

Implementing `wrap_t` like this does compile:

```
use std::mem;

fn wrap_t(&mut self) {
    unsafe {
        let old_t = mem::replace(&mut self.t, mem::uninitialized());
        let new_t = Box::new(Self::new(old_t));
        let uninit = mem::replace(&mut self.t, new_t);
        mem::forget(uninit);
    }
}
```

I wonder if there is a safe way to do this.

Comment: What behavior do you think should happen if the code panics once the value has been moved out once but before it is moved back?

Comment: See also [Change enum variant while moving the field to the new variant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36557412/155423); [Temporarily move out of borrowed content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29570781/155423).

Comment: @Shepmaster I don’t have a good answer. In my real program, I am only calling code that is guaranteed not to panic.

Answer (score 1):

The only `unsafe` function you are using is `mem::uninitialized`. You need something to pass to `mem::replace`, but implementing `Default` won't work because `default()` returns `Self`, which prevents it from being object-safe. Similarly, you can't implement `Clone` to duplicate the old value, since `clone()` also returns `Self`.

You can just implement a dummy type for the purpose though:

```
struct Dummy;
impl T for Dummy {}

fn wrap_t(&mut self) {
    let old_t = mem::replace(&mut self.t, Box::new(Dummy));
    let new_t = Box::new(Self::new(old_t));
    mem::replace(&mut self.t, new_t);
}
```

You also won't need the `mem::forget` here now either (I'm assuming that was there to prevent undefined behaviour when the uninitialised memory was dropped).

---

As an alternative to `Clone`, you can roll your own own, which clones to a `Box<dyn T>`, avoiding having a `Self` in the method signature, so the trait stays object safe:

```
trait T: Debug {
    fn clone_in_box(&self) -> Box<dyn T>;
}

impl T for S {
    fn clone_in_box(&self) -> Box<dyn T> {
        Box::new(S {
            t: self.t.clone_in_box(),
        })
    }
}
```

```
fn wrap_t(&mut self) {
    let cloned = self.clone_in_box();
    let old_t = mem::replace(&mut self.t, cloned);
    let new_t = Box::new(Self::new(old_t));
    mem::replace(&mut self.t, new_t);
}
```

---

There is also an alternative design, which is much simpler to understand when reading the code. That is just to consume `self` and return a new object:

```
fn wrap_t(self) -> Self {
    Self::new(Box::new(Self::new(self.t)))
}
```

And instead of this:

```
s.wrap_t();
```

You would do:

```
s = s.wrap_t();
```

Comment: The first solution will work, but it is a bit annoying since `T` might have a lot of methods. I guess for `Dummy` I would have to implement all those methods with stub implementations.

The second solution won't work for me, as `wrap_t` might be called from another method of `S`, so it does need to take `self` by reference.