# How to optionally normalize values when the conversion can fail?

Tags: rust

I wish to define a function that inspects two values and optionally changes one of them into a matching type. The motivation is to perform automatic casting for math formulas. My rules would be:

- Both are `i64`, leave alone
- Both are `f64`, leave alone
- One is `i64`, one is `f64`, change the `i64` to `f64`
- Other rules for other types

For example:

```
fn normalize(arg1: Option<MyValue>, arg2: Option<MyValue>) -> (Option<MyValue>, Option<MyValue>) {
    unimplemented!();
}
```

My example will return a tuple with the optionally transformed values. `MyValue` does not implement `Copy`, but it does implement `Clone`. It is an enum which can hold an integer or a rational or a string, etc.

The alternatives I can see are:

1. Return a tuple. Transform the value that needs to change, clone the other to avoid borrow-checker. Conversion failures come back as `None`.
2. Return a tuple. Transform the value that needs to change, return the other one unchanged, figure out how to move the value.
3. Return `()`. Make the parameters `&mut`. Change the one that needs to change, if any.
4. Some other way that I do not know about, because I am new to Rust.

Which approach is most idiomatic to Rust? If I do not clone, how do I notate the signature to placate the borrow-checker?

My real enum is:

```
#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Debug)]
pub enum ShyScalar {
    Boolean(bool),
    Integer(i64),
    Rational(f64),
    String(String),
    Error(String)
}
```

Comment: Can you make an enum that includes all of your acceptable types, and then a conversion operator on that enum which normalizes?

Comment: For simplicity, I did not show an extra parameter, the operator. The conversions are not the same for each operator. Think of arg1 as the left value, arg2 is the right value, and there is a binary operator between them. This normalization function will be attached to the operator Enum.

Comment: *Conversion failures ...* Like what?

Comment: This question is opinion-based and I've voted to close it as such. Pick one and try it. If it works, great. If it doesn't or it's annoying to use, pick another. If you exhaust your list of options, ask a new question looking for alternatives.

Comment: Because this question in its current form appears off-topic, you may wish to look at other resources. More open-ended questions and discussions are welcome on [the Rust subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/), [the Rust users forum](https://users.rust-lang.org/), or [the Rust Discord server](https://www.rust-lang.org/community).

Comment: My personal **opinion** is to use `&mut`, but see [Change enum variant while moving the field to the new variant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36557412/155423) for a reason you'd need to take by value.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of a trait with an associated type as a compile-time function that maps between types. For example:

```
trait MapType {
    type Output;
}

impl MapType for f64 {
    type Output i64;
}

impl MapType for bool {
    type Output u8;
}
```

For each type that you might need, you can implement `MapType` to provide a mapping to a unique `Output` type.

Your case is about pairs of types, and you can extend the idea above by adding a parameter:

```
trait Normalize<T>: Sized {
    type Norm;
}
```

Each implementation of `Normalize` produces a unique `Norm` type, for the combination of the two types, `Self` and `T`.

But you will also need some constraints; after all, you will need to be able to actually convert between these types. And if a number is too big to be converted, the conversion will fail, so you will need the extra type constraints, `TryFrom` and `TryInto`, to express which things can be converted into what:

```
use std::convert::{TryFrom, TryInto};

trait Normalize<T>: Sized
where
    T: TryInto<Self::Norm>,
{
    type Norm: TryFrom<Self>;
}
```

Implement it for the pairs of types you want:

```
impl Normalize<u32> for f64 {
    type Norm = f64;
}

impl Normalize<f64> for u32 {
    type Norm = f64;
}
```

And also for all pairs of *the same* type:

```
impl<X> Normalize<X> for X {
    type Norm = X;
}
```

You can then implement `normalize` like this:

```
fn normalize<A, B>(arg1: Option<A>, arg2: Option<B>) -> (Option<A::Norm>, Option<A::Norm>) 
where
    A: Normalize<B>,
    A::Norm: TryFrom<B>,
{
    (
        arg1.and_then(|a| a.try_into().ok()),
        arg2.and_then(|b| b.try_into().ok())
    )
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", normalize(Some(1u32), Some(1u32))); // (Some(1), Some(1))
    println!("{:?}", normalize(Some(1f64), Some(1u32))); // (Some(1.0), Some(1.0))
    println!("{:?}", normalize(Some(1u32), Some(1f64))); // (Some(1.0), Some(1.0))
    println!("{:?}", normalize(Some(1f64), Some(1f64))); // (Some(1.0), Some(1.0))
}
```

---

You will quickly realise that I have cheated a little here, by using `u32` instead of `u64`. That's because [there is no `TryFrom<u64>` implementation for `f64`](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/tryfrom-for-f64/9793/4). If you need these pairs of types then you can still keep the same approach as I have outlined, but you would need to define your own version of the `TryInto` and `TryFrom` traits and implement those yourself for all the types pairs that you need.