# How to change struct member enum's variant to another, moving the value?

Tags: rust, struct, enums, state-machine, borrow-checker

I am trying to implement a state machine for audio playback in Rust. A `Playback` struct can store a file and whether the playback is playing/paused/stopped, with playing/paused states saving playback position. The code is very simple:

```rust
struct PlaybackProgress {
    playback_position: f32,
    stream_id: usize
}


enum PlaybackState {
    Stopped,
    Playing(PlaybackProgress),
    Paused(PlaybackProgress)
}

struct Playback {
    file: Option<String>,
    state: PlaybackState,
}

impl Playback {
    // Creates a new empty Playback instance (no file, stopped)
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Playback {
            file: None,
            state: PlaybackState::Stopped
        }
    }

    pub fn play(&mut self, file: String) -> bool {
        match &self.state {
            PlaybackState::Playing(_) => {
                false
            }
            PlaybackState::Paused(progress) => {
                self.state = PlaybackState::Playing(progress); // THE ISSUE
                true
            }
            PlaybackState::Stopped => {
                self.file = Some(file);
                self.state = PlaybackState::Playing(PlaybackProgress { 
                    playback_position: 0.0, 
                    stream_id: 1 
                });
                true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is changing a `Paused` variant to a `Playing` while keeping the same progress. When trying `match self.state`, the compiler doesn't allow moving `progress`, and suggests borrowing (i.e. `match &self.state`), in which case there is a type mismatch between a reference and value.

I am confused why the issue is there, since the moved value would still be owned by parent struct and have the same lifetime as before.

What's a simple readable way to achieve this?

Note: I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36557412/how-can-i-change-enum-variant-while-moving-the-field-to-the-new-variant) and its answers, none of which worked. First answer suggests using an immutable value (impossible since this is a state machine and struct needs to be mutated), or storing a dummy value (impossible, when trying `*self.state` compiler says it cannot be dereferenced for reasons beyond my understanding). Other questions suggests using `unsafe` (which I won't do for such a simple task), or `Rc<>`/`Option<>`, which don't make sense in this case.

Comment: Since your state is pretty simple, the simplest way is probably to `#[derive (Copy, Clone)]` for `PlaybackProgress` and `PlaybackState`. Then you can just `match self.state`: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=1ef958d0bde2fe20dc35469eddd5fdc4).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Just to clarify, in that case `self.state = PlaybackState::Playing(progress)` will allocate a new `PlaybackProgress` struct, copy the values from the old one, and deallocate the old one? I am very new to the language so specifics of shadowing/moving are not fully clear.

Comment: There are no allocations in this code, in debug mode there may be copies of the `progress` values from `self.state` to the stack and back, but in release mode the compiler is smart enough to notice that you're putting the same values back in the same place and only change the discriminant: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/qKzfx6d9x).