# Polymorphic update on struct fields in Rust

Tags: rust, undefined-behavior, unsafe

Suppose I have a polymorphic type `T<A>`:

```rust
#[repr(C)]
pub struct T<A> {
    x: u32,
    y: Box<A>,
}
```

Below are my reasonings:

- According to the [Memory Layout Section of `std::boxed`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/index.html#memory-layout):

  > So long as `T: Sized`, a `Box<T>` is guaranteed to be represented as a single pointer and is also ABI-compatible with C pointers (i.e. the C type `T*`).

  So no matter what `A` is, `y` should have the same layout;
- Considering additionally the [`#[repr(C)]` attribute](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/other-reprs.html#reprc) on `T`, I expect that for all `A`s, `T<A>` would share the same layout;
- Thus I should be able to modify `y` in-place, even to values of a different type `Box<B>`.

My question is whether the following code is well-formed or has undefined behaviours? (The code below has been edited.)

```rust
fn update<A, B>(t: Box<T<A>>, f: impl FnOnce(A) -> B) -> Box<T<B>> {
    unsafe {
        let p = Box::into_raw(t);
        let a = std::ptr::read(&(*p).y);
        let q = p as *mut T<B>;
        std::ptr::write(&mut (*q).y, Box::new(f(*a)));
        Box::from_raw(q)
    }
}
```

Note:

The above code aims to perform a polymorphic update *in place*, so that the `x` field is left as-is. Imagine `x` were not simply a `u32`, but some very large chunk of data. The whole idea is to change the type of `y` (along with its value) without touching field `x`.

---

As is pointed out by Frxstrem, the code below indeed causes undefined behaviour. I made a silly mistake: I forgot to re-allocate memory for the `B` produced by `f`. It seems [the new code above passes Miri check](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ec5d11fa4192bccdbd27ce68c73b9781).

```rust
fn update<A, B>(t: Box<T<A>>, f: impl FnOnce(A) -> B) -> Box<T<B>> {
    unsafe {
        let mut u: Box<T<std::mem::MaybeUninit<B>>> = std::mem::transmute(t);
        let a = std::ptr::read::<A>(u.y.as_ptr() as *const _);
        u.y.as_mut_ptr().write(f(a));
        std::mem::transmute(u)
    }
}
```

Comment: [Miri says this is undefined behavior](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ec5d11fa4192bccdbd27ce68c73b9781)

Comment: [yep- I caused a segfault](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=13e61ba7007345257579b697d8fc0b12)

Comment: @Frxstrem I've updated the code. The previous code is incorrect in that it reuses the heap memory of `A` for the new object `B`. The new code passes Miri check. But this doesn't mean it's 100% correct, does it?

Comment: @RuifengXie That's right. Miri can find a lot of errors but doesn't guarantee that it will find all of them.

Comment: Seems like another variation on the `replace` theme. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29570781/temporarily-move-out-of-borrowed-content/60382120#60382120 for example. Your code probably misbehaves if `f` panics.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Got it. And what about other parts? Like where field `y` changes its type?

Comment: Adding on to what SebastianRedl said, [It leaks the allocation of `T` if `f` panics.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=abec2e4c1caa7a476580bf27e5b9865a) You also seem to be doing it right elsewhere with your revised `unsafe` code.

Comment: Please see my updated answer, I fixed the potential memory leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing yourself with the whole `T` stuff. This should be much easier to analyze. Specifically, read [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/index.html#memory-layout).

```
use core::mem::ManuallyDrop;
use core::alloc::Layout;

unsafe trait SharesLayout<T: Sized>: Sized {
    fn assert_same_layout() {
        assert!(Layout::new::<Self>() == Layout::new::<T>());
    }
}

/// Replaces the contents of a box, without reallocating.
fn box_map<A, B: SharesLayout<A>>(b: Box<A>, f: impl FnOnce(A) -> B) -> Box<B> {
    unsafe {
        B::assert_same_layout();
        let p = Box::into_raw(b);
        let mut dealloc_on_panic = Box::from_raw(p as *mut ManuallyDrop<A>);
        let new_content = f(ManuallyDrop::take(&mut *dealloc_on_panic));
        std::mem::forget(dealloc_on_panic);
        std::ptr::write(p as *mut B, new_content);
        Box::from_raw(p as *mut B)
    }
}
```

Then simply:

```
unsafe impl<A, B> SharesLayout<T<A>> for T<B> {}

fn update<A, B>(bt: Box<T<A>>, f: impl FnOnce(A) -> B) -> Box<T<B>> {
    box_map(bt, |t| {
        T { x: t.x, y: Box::new(f(*t.y))}
    })
}
```

Comment: I get the point for the `SharesLayout` trait, and how `DeallocOnDrop` prevents leaking. But if `x` is large in size, does the new `update` guarantee to avoid copying field `x`?

Comment: @RuifengXie Well, it gets moved, which *may* get optimized by the compiler, I don't know. Note that there's no `Copy` trait bounds anywhere.

Comment: Yes, certainly no copying in Rust's sense. By copying I meant `memcpy`. I believe in most circumstances it would be optimized out, but if the function to `box_map` is not inlined, the optimization would become impossible.

Comment: @RuifengXie I updated the implementation once more, eliminating the need for `DeallocOnDrop`.