# How to take, transform and replace a vector in a mutable reference?

Tags: rust

I have a `struct Database { events: Vec<Event> }`. I would like to apply some maps and filters to `events`. What is a good way to do this?

Here's what I tried:

```rust
fn update(db: &mut Database) {
    db.events = db.events.into_iter().filter(|e| !e.cancelled).collect();
}
```

This doesn't work:

```
cannot move out of `db.events` which is behind a mutable reference
...
move occurs because `db.events` has type `Vec<Event>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Is there any way to persuade Rust compiler that I'm taking the field value only temporarily?

Comment: [Temporarily move out of borrowed content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29570781/155423); [How can I swap in a new value for a field in a mutable reference to a structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27098694/155423).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The conceptual issue of why this doesn't work is due to panics. If, for example, the `filter` callback panics, then `db.events` would have been moved out of, by `into_iter`, but would not have had a value to replace it with - it would be uninitialized, and therefore unsafe.

Joël Hecht has what you really want to do in your specific instance: `Vec::retain` lets you filter out elements in place, and also reuses the storage.

Alexey Larionov also has an answer involving `Vec::drain`, which will leave an empty vector until the replacement happens. It requires a new allocation, though.

However, in the general case, the `replace_with` and `take_mut` crates offer functions to help accomplish what you are doing. You provide the function a closure that takes the value and returns its replacement, and the crates will run that closure, and aborting the process if there are panics.

Answer (score 4):

In the case you exposed, the safer way is to use `Vec.retain` :

```
fn update(db: &mut Database) {
    db.events.retain(|e| !e.cancelled);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to @Joël Hecht's answer, you can [`Vec::drain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.drain) the elements to then recreate the vector. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=66f2089aadc4fe5525a1ada5db41ee3f)

```
fn update(db: &mut Database) {
    db.events = db.events
        .drain(..)
        .filter(|e| !e.cancelled)
        .collect();
}
```