# Are there other options other than `Option` in rust patterns like this?

Tags: rust

On seldom occasions we have to invoke some data members' methods that take their ownership but we have only reference access like behind a `&mut self`. One pattern to deal with this is to wrap them in an `Option` type and `take()` them out to proceed.

Below is an example from the book:

```
struct Worker {
    id: usize,
    thread: Option<thread::JoinHandle<()>>,
}

pub struct ThreadPool {
    workers: Vec<Worker>,
    sender: Option<mpsc::Sender<Job>>,
}

impl Drop for ThreadPool {
    fn drop(&mut self) {

        drop(self.sender.take());

        for worker in &mut self.workers {
            if let Some(thread) = worker.thread.take() {
                thread.join().unwrap();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice `thread` and `sender` are wrapped in `Option` only to call `join` and `drop` in the destructor just before program exits. However almost their whole lifetime (except only before halt) they won't be `None`. The `Option` type used here *feels more like a work around rather than utilizing its semantic that there could be a value there or not* under norm.

Is this pattern prevalent in rust projects or are there some other options for this? My concern is that I may not be able to tell the 'real optional cases' from this seemingly dedicate usage quickly in code bases and there might be lots of `as_ref()` or `unwrap()` calls enforced.

Comment: `ManuallyDrop`. But that requires `unsafe` to work with, so it's usually fine to use `Option`s for a bit of extra safety.

Comment: You could use Option in combination with RefCell. This allows you to mutate the interior of the RefCell even if you only have a shared reference to it.

Comment: "However almost their whole lifetime (except only before halt) they won't be None" - then the branch predictor should have a pretty easy job.

Comment: It's entirely fine to use `Option` here. I'd strongly encourage not to use `ManuallyDrop`, because one needs some kind of flag to indicate wether these fields are safe to `drop()`, and that flag ends up doing exactly what `Option` already does.
There is a quality-of-life hassle with respect to all the `.unwrap()`ing, as you said. The question here is why the "uninitialized" state of `Worker` and `ThreadPool` even need to be possible. If the objects' constructors take care of always initializing these fields, there is no need for `Option`. Maybe you want to show your current constructor.

Comment: @user2722968 that's my point, it is only used for cleanup. The whole example is from here: https://rust-book.cs.brown.edu/ch20-03-graceful-shutdown-and-cleanup.html

Comment: In this case you could just `for worker in self.workers.drain(..)` to get owned access to the `Worker`s

Comment: @user1206899, I see. I tried to capture your specific point in the answer below.

Comment: @cafce25 That would work for `self.workers`, but not for `self.sender`, where they'd still need `Option`.

Comment: The question is answered by [Temporarily move out of borrowed content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29570781/temporarily-move-out-of-borrowed-content). However, I hesitate to close as duplicate since the code is in `drop()`, which have another solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find `Option` unwieldy, an alternative is to avoid `Drop` altogether. This would allow you to "partially move" from `self`:

```
struct Worker {
    id: usize,
    thread: JoinHandle<()>,
}

pub struct ThreadPool {
    workers: Vec<Worker>,
    sender: Sender<Job>,
}

impl ThreadPool {
    pub fn wait(self) {
        drop(self.sender);
        for worker in self.workers {
            worker.thread.join().unwrap();
        }
    }
}
```

A slightly more involved alternative is to retain `Drop` and use `std::mem::replace()` to obtain an owned value out of `&mut self`. Since `Drop` doesn't allow partial moves, it requires splitting the type to an outer one that implements `Drop` and the inner one that doesn't. (But this split is zero-cost at run-time.)

```
// definition of Worker unchanged from above

pub struct ThreadPool {
    inner: ThreadPoolInner,
}

struct ThreadPoolInner {
    workers: Vec<Worker>,
    sender: Sender<Job>,
}

impl ThreadPoolInner {
    fn wait(self) {
        drop(self.sender);
        for worker in self.workers {
            worker.thread.join().unwrap();
        }
    }
}

impl Drop for ThreadPool {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        let empty = ThreadPoolInner {
            workers: vec![],
            sender: mpsc::channel::<Job>().0,
        };
        let owned_inner = std::mem::replace(&mut self.inner, empty);
        owned_inner.wait(); // or inline wait() if you don't want it as separate method
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=35f1a5dd10d31601d18adcf34e802ca1)

This looks a bit strange at first, but it has the benefit of retaining the convenient `Drop`-based interface without the overhead of `Option`, all in safe code.

Comment: Nice, but with some minor issues. `std::mem::replace(&mut self, empty)` seems to be `std::mem::replace(self, empty)` and my compiler complains 'error[E0509]: cannot move out of type `ThreadPool`, which implements the `Drop` trait' to `drop(self.sender);`  which I don't know how to fix at the moment.

Comment: @user1206899 Serves me right for not testing the code. Fixed now, please see edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `Option` *only* for cleanup might seem cumbersome, because - after all - the `None` case only ever happens *while* the object is being destroyed, right before it *has been* destroyed; but one pays to cost every single time, as every single field access needs a useless check that boils down to "Am I currently being destroyed? No!".

This pattern, while cumbersome, is entirely fine. If your types gets bigger and more complicated, you might want to split them into different parts or rely on type-states to prevent the quality-of-life hassle of `Option` "leaking into" every single field access.

There is a deeper reason here why this pattern can't be avoided entirely: The destructor of `ThreadPool` is not some reduced subset of Rust, but can be as complex as the programmer desires (e.g. `fn drop(&mut self) { if random() == 42 { self.prove_riemann_hypothesis_recursive(); }`). This means that the compiler can make only the very generic assumptions about the behavior of the destructor as it can for any other function. While in your example this does not occur, it is entirely possible that `ThreadPool` contains another `ThreadPool` inside of it; or a `&mut ThreadPool` which sometimes but not always just so happens to refer back to it's own owner (see [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/dropck.html) for an example of this situation). Because the destructor can reach back into the object being destroyed, and because the destructor is - at first approximation - just another function, we *must* encode the type in such a way that is safe in *all* situations. The graveyard of memory-bugs is filled nine feet deep with invalid memory accesses which were introduced in some method that didn't take into account it might get *executed by the destructor on a partially destroyed object*.