# Can I destructure a tuple without binding the result to a new variable in a let/match/for statement?

Tags: rust

I'd like to destructure a tuple and assign part of the result to a new variable and assign another part of the result to an existing.

The following code illustrates the intent (it's a dumb example which results in an infinite loop printing `[0]`):

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut list = &[0, 1, 2, 3][..];
    while !list.is_empty() {
        let (head, list) = list.split_at(1);
        // An obvious workaround here is to introduce a new variable in the above
        // let statement, and then just assign it to list.
        println!("{:?}", head);
    }
}
```

This code creates a new variable `list` instead of reassigning it.

If I change the code to the following (to avoid the `let` that introduces the new `list` variable), it doesn't compile:

```
fn main() {
    let mut list = &[0, 1, 2, 3][..];
    while !list.is_empty() {
        let head;
        (head, list) = list.split_at(1);
        println!("{:?}", head);
    }
}
```

Compilation error:

```
error[E0070]: invalid left-hand side of assignment
 --> src/main.rs:5:22
  |
5 |         (head, list) = list.split_at(1);
  |         ------------ ^
  |         |
  |         cannot assign to this expression
  |
```

Is there a way to do this, or can destructuring only be used in `let`, `match`, and `for` statements?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No.

Destructuring is something you can only do with patterns; the left-hand side of an assignment is *not* a pattern, hence you can't destructure-and-assign.

See [proto-RFC 372 (Destructuring assignment)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/372) which discusses the possibility of adding this feature.

Comment: Added as of Rustc 1.59.0

Answer (score 22):

Yes.

The Rust team has published a new version of Rust 1.59.0 in Feb. 24, 2022, you can now use tuple, slice, and struct patterns as the left-hand side of an assignment.

[Announcing Rust 1.59.0](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2022/02/24/Rust-1.59.0.html)

> #### Destructuring assignments
>
> You can now use tuple, slice, and struct patterns as the left-hand side of an assignment.
>
> ```
> let (a, b, c, d, e);
>
> (a, b) = (1, 2); [c, .., d, _] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; Struct { e, .. } =
> Struct { e: 5, f: 3 };
>
> assert_eq!([1, 2, 1, 4, 5], [a, b, c, d, e]);
> ```
>
> This makes assignment more consistent with let bindings, which have
> long supported the same thing. Note that destructuring assignments
> with operators such as += are not allowed.

Before 1.59.0, you can only destructure it in Nightly version with `#![feature(destructuring_assignment)]`.

Now you can do this trick in stable version and remove the feature line.

See more details from [rust-lang/rust/issues/71126](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/71126) and [rust-lang/rust/pull/90521](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/90521).

Answer (score 4):

Nightly Rust has [`feature(destructuring_assignment)`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/71126), which allows your original attempt to compile as-is:

```rust
#![feature(destructuring_assignment)]

fn main() {
    let mut list = &[0, 1, 2, 3][..];
    while !list.is_empty() {
        let head;
        (head, list) = list.split_at(1);
        println!("{:?}", head);
    }
}
```

```
[0]
[1]
[2]
[3]
```

---

However, I'd solve this using stable features like slice pattern matching, which avoids the need for the double check in `split_at` and `is_empty`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut list = &[0, 1, 2, 3][..];

    while let [head, rest @ ..] = list {
        println!("{:?}", head);
        list = rest;
    }
}
```

See also:

- [How to swap two variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31798737/155423)