# Tuples not allowed as lvalue in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have a few methods in Rust that return two elements, and it really makes sense for me in those scenarios to return two elements. Though, when actually calling those methods I noticed that Rust does not allow using tuples as lvalue, so I cannot reassign to them. Assuming `test()` is a method that returns two values, I end up writing a lot of code that looks like this:

```
let (mut val1, mut val2) = test();

for i in 0..100 {
   // partially removed for brevity;
   let (_val1, _val2) = test();
   val1 = _val1;
   val2 = _val2;
}

let (_val1, _val2) = test();
val1 = _val1;
val2 = _val2;
```

Usually the two values that are returned from my method are some structures, and in turn they have some methods too, so I want to call methods in those returned structs. Anyway, I use the above pattern a lot, and it becomes cumbersome very fast. Are there any better approaches to do what I want in Rust?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I destructure a tuple without binding the result to a new variable in a let/match/for statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304341/can-i-destructure-a-tuple-without-binding-the-result-to-a-new-variable-in-a-let)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a macro

```
macro_rules! assign{
    {($v1:ident, $v2:ident) = $e:expr} =>
    {
        let (v1, v2) = $e;
        $v1 = v1;
        $v2 = v2;
    };
    {($v1:ident, $v2:ident, $v3:ident) = $e:expr} =>
    {
        let (v1, v2, v3) = $e;
        $v1 = v1;
        $v2 = v2;
        $v3 = v3;
    }; // and so on
}
```

and use it like this

```
assign!{(val1, val2) = test()};
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=429c882261fd1c3a247a7c722dd9f57c&version=stable)