# Return last n elements of vector in Rust without mutating the vector

Tags: vector, rust

I  am struggling to find a way to take two values from the end of a vector, sum those values, and push the sum to the vector.

I have found that `pop`, `truncate`, and `drain` do not work because they remove the values from the original vector.

```
fn main() {
    println!("Which Fibonacci number would you like to find?");

    let mut fib_num = String::new();

    io::stdin().read_line(&mut fib_num)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    let fib_num: u32 = fib_num.trim().parse()
        .expect("Please enter a number");

    let mut stored_nums: Vec<u32> = vec![0, 1];

    while fib_num > stored_nums.len() as u32 {
        let mut limit = stored_nums.len();
        let mut new_num1 = stored_nums.pop().unwrap();
        let mut new_num2 = stored_nums.pop().unwrap_or(0);
        stored_nums.push(new_num1 + new_num2);
    }
}
```

Comment: `pop` removes the last one, use `last` to access it by reference without removing it.

Comment: @Boiethios last does not take parameters, though, right?  If I could call `blahblah.last(2)` to get the last two items that would be perfect.

Comment: It was a little piece of advice. See the answer of Shepmaster.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to consider the case where the vector *doesn't have two items*.

I'd use iterator adapters like [`Iterator::rev`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.rev) and [`Iterator::take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.take) and then finish with [`Iterator::sum`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.sum):

```
let sum = stored_nums.iter().rev().take(2).sum();
stored_nums.push(sum);
```

This allows you to avoid *explicit* handling of cases where the vector / slice / iterator is too short but the code still deals with it implicitly.

---

You could also directly index into the slice:

```
let len = stored_nums.len();
let sum = stored_nums[len - 1] + stored_nums[len - 2];
stored_nums.push(sum);
```

This will panic if there are less than 2 elements, however.

You could attempt to deal with the vector being too short in this case, but it's a bit verbose:

```
fn add_last_two(nums: &[u32]) -> Option<u32> {
    let len = nums.len();

    let idx_a = len.checked_sub(1)?;
    let idx_b = len.checked_sub(2)?;

    let a = nums.get(idx_a)?;
    let b = nums.get(idx_b)?;

    Some(a + b)
}

fn main() {
    let mut stored_nums: Vec<u32> = vec![0, 1];
    let sum = add_last_two(&stored_nums).unwrap_or(0);
    stored_nums.push(sum);
}
```

---

Note that it might be nicer to use [a Fibonacci iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31798737/155423) and just `collect` that into a `Vec`.

Comment: Iterator is the way to go.  Thanks.  Because I'm prepopulating the vec with two items I didn't think to worry about the case where there might not be two items.  I also changed my integer type to u64 as u32 topped out at <50th number in the sequence.

Answer (score 10):

To retrieve the last n elements, you could just convert it to a slice.

E.g. Get last 3 elements:

```rust
let v = vec![0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
let last3 = v.as_slice()[v.len()-3..].to_vec();

println!("{:?}", last3); // [7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a reverse iterator on the `Vec`:

```
let (n1, n2) = {
    let mut rev_iter = stored_nums.iter().rev();
    (rev_iter.next().unwrap().clone(), rev_iter.next().unwrap().clone())
};
stored_nums.push(n1 + n2);
```

Comment: The behavior of calling `next` after an iterator returns `None` the first time is undefined. This answer calls `next` multiple times *without* checking if each preceding one is `None`, thus it can lead to unexpected results.

Comment: @Shepmaster I know. The length of the vector does not go under 2, and I call `next` 2 times only, so there is no problem.

Comment: The *example* provided never goes below 2 elements, but the *question* is more general than the example.

Comment: My answer is very contextual and did not aimed to give a general answer. Anyway, your answer is better as usual 