# How to assign 2 variables simultaneously in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm currently teaching myself Rust with a roguelike tutorial, and I'm attempting to get a key press to move a character diagonally which would mean `player_x -=1`, `player_y -= 1` for up left.

No matter which way I try to arrange the code, I keep getting error messages from the compiler. I couldn't find any example of this anywhere in the documentation or on GitHub.

```
Key { code: Escape, .. } => return true, // exit game

// movement keys
Key { code: Up, .. } => *player_y -= 1,
Key { code: Down, .. } => *player_y += 1,
Key { code: Left, .. } => *player_x -= 1,
Key { code: Right, .. } => *player_x += 1,
Key { printable: 'k', .. } => *player_y -= 1,
Key { printable: 'k', .. } => *player_x -= 1,

_ => {}
```

You can kind of see what I'm trying to do here, but this throws an error message saying the pattern is unreachable, how would I fix this code?

Here's [the full code](https://hastebin.com/exiwageluv.php), it's fairly small, not sure what would be alone necessary to compile:

```
extern crate tcod;
extern crate input;

use tcod::console::*;
use tcod::colors;

// actual size of the window
const SCREEN_WIDTH: i32 = 80;
const SCREEN_HEIGHT: i32 = 50;

const LIMIT_FPS: i32 = 20;  // 20 frames-per-second maximum


fn handle_keys(root: &mut Root, player_x: &mut i32, player_y: &mut i32) -> bool {
    use tcod::input::Key;
    use tcod::input::KeyCode::*;

    let key = root.wait_for_keypress(true);
    match key {
        Key { code: Enter, alt: true, .. } => {
            // Alt+Enter: toggle fullscreen
            let fullscreen = root.is_fullscreen();
            root.set_fullscreen(!fullscreen);
        }
        Key { code: Escape, .. } => return true,  // exit game

        // movement keys
        Key { code: Up, .. } => *player_y -= 1,
        Key { code: Down, .. } => *player_y += 1,
        Key { code: Left, .. } => *player_x -= 1,
        Key { code: Right, .. } => *player_x += 1,
        Key { printable: 'k', ..} => *player_y -= 1,
        Key { printable: 'k', ..} => *player_x -= 1,

        _ => {},
    }

    false
}

fn main() {
    let mut root = Root::initializer()
        .font("terminal8x8_gs_tc.png", FontLayout::Tcod)
        .font_type(FontType::Greyscale)
        .size(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
        .title("Rust/libtcod tutorial")
        .init();

    tcod::system::set_fps(LIMIT_FPS);

    let mut player_x = SCREEN_WIDTH / 2;
    let mut player_y = SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2;

    while !root.window_closed() {
        root.set_default_foreground(colors::WHITE);
        root.put_char(player_x, player_y, '@', BackgroundFlag::None);

        root.flush();

        root.put_char(player_x, player_y, ' ', BackgroundFlag::None);

        // handle keys and exit game if needed
        let exit = handle_keys(&mut root, &mut player_x, &mut player_y);
        if exit {
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve the question if possible, it's been a while since I've been to stackoverflow

Comment: It's common practice to provide a [MCVE], but you've provided a handwavy bit of code that no one else is able to compile.

Comment: ah ok, ill post my whole code then

Comment: **Not** whole code. **Minimal** code.

Comment: It's fairly small code and im not sure what would alone be needed to compile so I added a hastebin link if thats kosher.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How to assign 2 variables simultaneously in Rust?

You cannot. You can bind two variables at once:

```
let (a, b) = (1, 2);
```

If you aren't trying to create new bindings, you need to have two assignment statements:

```
let mut a = 1;
let mut b = 2;

a = 3;
b = 4;
```

In your case, for a match statement, you need to introduce a block:

```
let key = 42;
let mut a = 1;
let mut b = 2;

match key {
    0 => {
        a += 1;
        b -= 1;
    }
    _ => {
        a -= 10;
        b *= 100;
    }
}
```

You could also have the `match` expression evaluate to a tuple, which you then create new bindings for and apply them afterwards:

```
let key = 42;
let mut x = 1;
let mut y = 2;

let (d_x, d_y) = match key {
    0 => (1, -1),
    _ => (10, 10),
};

x += d_x;
y += d_y;
```

I **strongly** recommend reading [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/) instead of trying to learn Rust by intuition or trial and error. It has an [entire chapter on the match statement](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch06-02-match.html).

See also:

- [How to swap two variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31798737/155423)

Comment: Awesome! That helped me grokk this, thanks for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 1):

The second `printable: 'k'` is unreachable, since the first will match instead.  What you want is doing both assignments in the same arm of the match, like this:

```
Key { printable: 'k', .. } => {
    *player_y -= 1;
    *player_x -= 1;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! This syntax was just what I was looking for, would have never guessed using the semi colon's there, thank you!