# How to swap two numbers?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to swap two integers in Rust without any library.

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut a = 5;
    let mut b = 6;
    swap(&mut a, &mut b);
    println!("{}, {}", a, b); // expecting 6, 5
}
```

First I've tried:

```rust
fn swap(mut a: &mut u32, mut b: &mut u32) {
    (a, b) = (b, a); // destructuring assignments are not currently supported
}
```

Then:

```rust
fn swap(mut a: &mut u32, mut b: &mut u32) {
    let temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
// got error[E0623]: lifetime mismatch
```

Finally:

```rust
fn swap<'a>(mut a: &'a mut u32, mut b: &'a mut u32) {
    let temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
// still does not work; when this scope ends a and b in `main()` are still 5 and 6 respectively
// got warning: value assigned to `a` is never read (for `b` as well)
```

I don't know what's wrong; last implementation looks cumbersome to me but I think it should work as I am passing mutable reference to function, but it does not work.

Comment: You are assigning the references, not the referred to values. Try `temp=*a` and so on.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to swap two variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31798737/how-to-swap-two-variables)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can *dereference* references:

```
fn swap(a: &mut u32, b: &mut u32) {
    let t: u32 = *a; // Read the integer with `*a`
    *a = *b; // Write to the reference with `*a = <stuff>`
    *b = t;
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = 6;
    let mut b = 7;
    
    println!("{}, {}", a, b);
    swap(&mut a, &mut b);
    println!("{}, {}", a, b);
}
```

Output:

```
6, 7
7, 6
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=643137d9141564ec03241a63e134dd84)

Answer (score 7):

The efficient way:

```
use std::mem;

let mut x = 5;
let mut y = 42;

mem::swap(&mut x, &mut y);

assert_eq!(42, x);
assert_eq!(5, y);
```

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.swap.html

Comment: I wanted to do without standard library but thanks anyway.

Comment: @109149, you could use [`core::mem::swap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/mem/fn.swap.html) - it's from the core library

Comment: @109149 Please include such restrictions in your questions, so people don't risk wasting their time by failing to meet criteria that you didn't specify.

Comment: I see, I've modified it.

Answer (score 2):

For copyable types this is quite succinct (if you prefer not to use `std::mem::swap`:

```rust
fn swap<T: Copy>(a: T, b: T) -> (T, T) {
    (b, a)
}

fn main() {
    let (a, b) = (1, 2);
    let (a, b) = swap(a, b);

    println!("A: {}, B: {}", a, b);

    // Note you can also just do this
    let (a, b) = (b, a);

    println!("A: {}, B: {}", a, b);
}
```

Comment: I don't really see the point of this answer. Swapping two variables only makes sense if you actually mutate existing variables. This creates two new variables which happen to have swapped names, but it doesn't mutate any existing variables. Instead of doing this, you can also just swap the names in the remainder of the function.