# How can I take ownership of a Vec element and replace it with something else?

Tags: vector, rust, lifetime, ownership

I am writing a function of the following format:

```
fn pop<T>(data: &mut Vec<Option<T>>) -> Option<T> {
    // Let the item be the current element at head
    let item = data[0];

    // and "remove" it.
    data[0] = None;

    item
}
```

When I try to do this, I get an error which makes sense:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of index of `std::vec::Vec<std::option::Option<T>>`
 --> src/lib.rs:3:16
  |
3 |     let item = data[0];
  |                ^^^^^^^ move occurs because value has type `std::option::Option<T>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
  |
help: consider borrowing the `Option`'s content
  |
3 |     let item = data[0].as_ref();
  |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: consider borrowing here
  |
3 |     let item = &data[0];
  |                ^^^^^^^^
```

When I try to change it such that `item` is a reference, I get an error when I try to set `data[0]` to `None`, which also makes sense.

Is there some way I can do what I want to do? It seems to me that, whether I want to return a reference or not, I'm going to have to take ownership of the element from the Vec.

I noticed that `Vec` has a `swap_remove` method, which does almost exactly what I want, except that it swaps with an element already in the `Vec`, not with any arbitrary value as I would like. I know that I could just append `None` to the end of the `Vec` and use `swap_remove`, but I'm interested in seeing if there's another way.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use [`std::mem::replace`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/fn.replace.html):

```
use std::mem;

fn pop<T>(data: &mut Vec<Option<T>>) -> Option<T> {
    mem::replace(&mut data[0], None)
}
```

`replace` essentially replaces the value in a particular location with another one and returns the previous value.

See also:

- [How can I swap in a new value for a field in a mutable reference to a structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27098694/155423)

Comment: BTW, for replacing an optional value with `None` there is a special method on `Option`, called [`take()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/option/enum.Option.html#method.take). I'd say it is more idiomatic to use it instead of `replace()`, where applicable.

Comment: I cannot believe there isn't a method on vec itself