# Take member ownership of borrowed struct

Tags: rust, ownership, borrow-checker

I have the following function:

```
pub fn finish_frame(&mut self) {
    if self.frame.is_none() {
        return;
    }

    self.frame.unwrap().finish().unwrap();
}
```

When I compile, the compiler gives me the following error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/engine/renderer.rs:65:9
   |
65 |         self.frame.unwrap().finish().unwrap();
   |         ^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

`self.frame` is a `Option` type, `finish(mut self)` takes ownership of `self`. Since `finish(mut self)` is a library function, I cannot change that.

Any idea on how I could do this? Ideally without implementing a copy trait, which feels like a waste of memory and CPU time.

I am a Rust newbie, so please forgive me if this is a stupid mistake.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/33705664/155423; http://stackoverflow.com/q/27098694/155423; http://stackoverflow.com/q/33204273/155423; or http://stackoverflow.com/q/38776577/155423, take your pick.

Comment: @Shepmaster the second one helped me! Thanks!

Comment: Great! I just added another answer to that one with a special case that is likely to be helpful to your exact situation.