# How can I modify a slice that is a function parameter?

Tags: rust

Parameters can be passed to functions and modified:

```
fn set_42(int: &mut i32) {
    *int += 42;
}

fn main() {
    let mut int = 0;
    set_42(&mut int);
    println!("{:?}", int);
}
```

[Output](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5b4bf5e3c01b23722360836b11658b06):

```
42
```

---

Changing the code to use a slice fails with a whole bunch of errors:

```
fn pop_front(slice: &mut [i32]) {
    *slice = &{slice}[1..];
}

fn main() {
    let mut slice = &[0, 1, 2, 3][..];
    pop_front(&mut slice);
    println!("{:?}", slice);
}
```

[Output](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a11eea7cc0ce87f2fc090af821250337):

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:2:14
  |
2 |     *slice = &{ slice }[1..];
  |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |              |
  |              expected slice `[i32]`, found `&[i32]`
  |              help: consider removing the borrow: `{ slice }[1..]`

error[E0277]: the size for values of type `[i32]` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/main.rs:2:5
  |
2 |     *slice = &{ slice }[1..];
  |     ^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `[i32]`
  = note: to learn more, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-the-sized-trait>
  = note: the left-hand-side of an assignment must have a statically known size
```

---

If we try using a mutable slice (which isn't what I really want; I don't want to modify the values within the slice, I just want to modify the slice itself so it covers a smaller range of elements) and a mutable parameter, it has no effect on the original slice:

```
fn pop_front(mut slice: &mut [i32]) {
    slice = &mut {slice}[1..];
}

fn main() {
    let mut slice = &mut [0, 1, 2, 3][..];
    pop_front(&mut slice);
    println!("{:?}", slice);
}
```

[Output](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6ceac9eee130dab8f82f667acd11efea):

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

---

Is there a way to modify a slice that's a function parameter? I don't want to modify the elements within the slice; I just want to modify the range of the slice itself so it becomes a smaller "sub-slice".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As others have said, the core idea here is to take a `&mut &... [T]` (where `...` is `mut` or empty) and read/write to the internal slice. The other answers demonstrate it is possible for `&mut &[T]` in safe code, and possible for `&mut &mut [T]` with unsafe code, but they don't explain why there's the difference... and `&mut &mut [T]` is possible with safe code too.

In explicit-lifetime terms, the nested reference is something like `&'a mut &'b ... [T]` for some lifetimes `'a` and '`b`, and the goal here is to get a `&'b ... [T]`, slice it and write that into the `&'a mut`.

For `&'a mut &'b [T]`, this is easy: `&[T]` is copy, so writing `*slice = &slice[1..]` will effectively copy the `&'b [T]` out of the `&mut` and then, later, overwrite the existing value with the shorter one. The copy means that one literally gets a `&'b [T]` to operate with, and so there's no direct connection between that and the `&'a mut`, and hence it is legal to mutate. It is effectively something like

```
fn pop_front<'a, 'b>(slice: &'a mut &'b[i32]) {
    // *slice = &slice[1..] behaves like
    let value: &'b [i32] = *slice;
    *slice = &value[1..]
}
```

(I've labelled the lifetimes and annotated the type to tie into my explanation, but this is not required for the code to work.)

For `&'a mut &'b mut [T]` things are a little trickier: `&mut [T]` cannot be copied: dereferencing won't copy, it will reborrow to give a `&'a mut [T]` i.e. the slice has a lifetime that is connected to the *outer* `&'a mut`, not the inner `&'b mut [T]`. This means the sliced reference has a shorter lifetime than the type it is trying to overwrite, so it's invalid to store the slice into that position. In other words:

```
fn pop_front<'a, 'b>(slice: &'a mut &'b mut [i32]) {
    let value: &'a mut [i32] = &mut **slice;
    *slice = &mut value[1..] // error
}
```

The way to do this safely for `&'a mut &'b mut [T]` is to get the internal slice out of the reference with that `'b` lifetime. This requires keeping track of the "one owner" rule, doing no borrowing, and the best function for this sort of ownership manipulation is [`mem::replace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.replace.html). It allows us to extract the inner `&'b mut [T]` by swapping it with some placeholder, which we can then overwrite with the short version. The best/only placeholder is an empty array: writing `&mut []` can be a `&'c mut [X]` for any type `X` and any lifetime `'c`, since there's no data to store and so nothing needs initialisation, and no data will ever become invalid. In particular, it can be a `&'b mut [T]`:

```
fn pop_front<'a, 'b>(slice: &'a mut &'b mut [i32]) {
    let value: &'b mut [i32] = mem::replace(slice, &mut []);
    *slice = &mut value[1..]
}
```

Since `&mut[T]` implements `Default`, we can also use [`mem::take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.take.html):

```
fn pop_front<'a, 'b>(slice: &'a mut &'b mut [i32]) {
    let value: &'b mut [i32] = mem::take(slice);
    *slice = &mut value[1..]
}
```

(As above, I've made things more explicit than necessary.)

See also:

- [Why can't I assign one dereference of a reference of a reference to another when the outer lifetimes differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61195410/155423)
- [Why does linking lifetimes matter only with mutable references?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32165917/3650362)
- [How can I swap in a new value for a field in a mutable reference to a structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27098694/155423)

Answer (score 5):

If you need to modify an immutable slice, [see Cornstalks's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34384487/234590).

You cannot modify a mutable slice in safe Rust. When you take a subslice of a mutable slice, you effectively borrow from the original slice. This means that the subslice must not outlive the original slice.

You want something that looks like this:

```
fn pop_front(slice: &mut &mut [i32]) {
    *slice = &mut slice[1..];
}
```

but the subslice `slice[1..]` is only valid until the end of the function, and which point the borrow will end and the original slice (the `slice` parameter) will be usable again.

We can use some `unsafe` code to construct manually the slice we want:

```
use std::slice;

fn pop_front(slice: &mut &mut [i32]) {
    let ptr = slice.as_mut_ptr();
    let len = slice.len();
    *slice = unsafe { slice::from_raw_parts_mut(ptr.offset(1), len - 1) };
}

fn main() {
    let mut slice = &mut [0, 1, 2, 3][..];
    pop_front(&mut slice);
    println!("{:?}", slice);
}
```

[playground](http://is.gd/0svRzz)

This program outputs:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 4):

Using part of [Francis Gagné's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34384326/1287251) (I didn't think of trying `&mut &`), I was able to get it working without using `unsafe` code:

```
fn pop_front(mut slice: &mut &[i32]) {
    *slice = &slice[1..];
}

fn main() {
    let mut slice = &[0, 1, 2, 3][..];
    pop_front(&mut slice);
    println!("{:?}", slice);
}
```

[Output](http://is.gd/wOfEq1):

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: This mutates an immutable slice, not a mutable slice. It's not clear from the question what was the OP's need...

Comment: @FrancisGagné: this is what I was trying to ask for in my question, though to be honest I'm using mutable slices in my real code so your answer was very helpful there. I was having a hard time trying to sensibly talk about mutable immutable slices in my question, because "mutable immutable" sounds nonsensical (but is probably the correct term).

Comment: Your `pop_front` takes a mutable *reference* to an immutable *slice*. My `pop_front` takes a mutable reference to a mutable slice.

Comment: @FrancisGagné: that wording sounds much better. Thanks for all your help! I wish I had more than one upvote to give you.