# Why can't I assign one dereference of a reference of a reference to another when the outer lifetimes differ?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I want to write the following function:

```
fn foo<'a, 'b, 'c>(rr1: &'a mut &'c mut u32, rr2: &'b mut &'c mut u32) {
    *rr1 = *rr2;
}
```

But the compiler complains:

```
error[E0623]: lifetime mismatch
 --> src/lib.rs:2:12
  |
1 | fn foo<'a, 'b, 'c>(rr1: &'a mut &'c mut u32, rr2: &'b mut &'c mut u32) {
  |                                 -----------       ------------------- these two types are declared with different lifetimes...
2 |     *rr1 = *rr2;
  |            ^^^^ ...but data from `rr2` flows into `rr1` here
```

My mental model of Rust's lifetimes does not agree that the code is wrong. I read the type of `rr2` as "A reference with lifetime `'b` to a reference with lifetime `'c` to an `u32`". Thus when I dereference `rr2`, I get a reference with lifetime `'c` to an `u32`. This should be safe to store in `*rr1`, which has the same type.

If I require that `'b` outlives `'c`, it works:

```
fn foo<'a, 'b: 'c, 'c>(rr1: &'a mut &'c mut u32, rr2: &'b mut &'c mut u32) {
    *rr1 = *rr2;
}
```

This makes me think that the type `&'b mut &'c mut u32` means the `u32` at the end of the reference chain is only available during the intersection of `'b` and `'c`.

What is the right explanation for Rust's behavior here? And why do references of references behave this way instead of the way I thought they do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot dereference a `&'b mut &'c mut u32` and get a `&'c mut u32` because:

- `&mut` references are not trivially copiable, so you can't **copy** the `&'c mut u32`; and
- You cannot move out of a reference, so you also can't **move** the `&'c mut u32` (which would leave the outer reference dangling).

Instead, the compiler **reborrows** the `u32` with the outer lifetime, `'b`. This is why you get an error message that data from `rr2` flows into `rr1`.

If `foo` were allowed to compile, you could use it to get two `&mut` references to the same `u32`, which is forbidden by the rules of references:

```
let (mut x, mut y) = (10, 20);
let mut rx = &mut x;
let mut ry = &mut y;
foo(&mut rx, &mut ry); // rx and ry now both refer to y
std::mem::swap(rx, ry); // undefined behavior!
```

> If I require that 'b outlives 'c, it works

Because `'c` must already outlive `'b`¹, if you require that `'b` also outlives `'c`, it follows that `'c` = `'b`. The updated signature is equivalent to this:

```
fn foo<'a, 'b>(rr1: &'a mut &'b mut u32, rr2: &'b mut &'b mut u32)
```

That is, you have unified `'c` and `'b`, and now there's no problem borrowing a `&'b mut u32` from `rr2` because the inner and outer lifetimes both live for `'b`. However, the compiler now won't let you write the broken code in the example I gave earlier, since `ry` is already borrowed for its entire lifetime.

Interestingly, if you make the inner reference non-`mut`, it also works:

```
fn foo<'a, 'b, 'c>(rr1: &'a mut &'c u32, rr2: &'b mut &'c u32) {
    *rr1 = *rr2;
}
```

This is because `&` references are `Copy`, so `*rr2` is not a reborrow, but actually just a copy of the inner value.

For more information, read:

- [Why does linking lifetimes matter only with mutable references?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32165917/3650362)
- [How can I modify a slice that is a function parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34384089/3650362)

---

¹ It might not be obvious why `'c` outlives `'b` when there is no explicit `'c: 'b` bound. The reason is because the compiler assumes that the type `&'b mut &'c mut u32` is *well-formed*. Well-formedness can become complex (see [RFC 1214](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1214-projections-lifetimes-and-wf.html)) but in this case it just means you can't have a reference that's valid for longer (`'b`) than the thing it references (`'c`).

Comment: I've been looking for a reference link for implicit reborrows for a while now. Do you happen to have one? It doesn't seem to be mentioned in the Rust reference at all, but "because of implicit reborrows" has been the answer to a fair number of questions over the recent years.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Unfortunately, if I had one, I would have linked to it (and I'd probably have a few older answers to update too!) I don't think it's in the Nomicon either.