# Why do multiple mutable references make it impossible to assign a struct's member to itself?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm not able to borrow where I thought I could. I reduced the problem down to this case:

```rust
struct A<'a> {
    borrow: &'a mut u8,
}

fn does_nothing<'b, 'c>(a: &'b mut A<'c>) {
    a.borrow = a.borrow;
}
```

```
error[E0623]: lifetime mismatch
 --> src/lib.rs:6:16
  |
5 | fn does_nothing<'b, 'c>(a: &'b mut A<'c>) {
  |                            -------------
  |                            |
  |                            these two types are declared with different lifetimes...
6 |     a.borrow = a.borrow;
  |                ^^^^^^^^ ...but data from `a` flows into `a` here
```

It seems that `a.borrow` has the intersection of `'b` and `'c` and therefore cannot be guaranteed to still have the lifetime `'c`.

I don't have any real problem with this and can work around it by making both lifetimes the same, but why this does not borrow check?

---

It seems structs are unimportant to showing this issue and double borrows show it easily.

I have three functions which are pretty similar, but I would have trouble knowing which one compiles and which error the non-compiling ones would give.

The simple generic function:

```rust
fn only_borrow<T>(a: &mut T) {
    *a = *a;
}
```

results in the error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*a` which is behind a mutable reference
 --> src/lib.rs:2:10
  |
2 |     *a = *a;
  |          ^^ move occurs because `*a` has type `T`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Including an extra level of indirection changes the error

```rust
fn only_borrow_double<T>(a: &mut &mut T) {
    *a = *a;
}
```

```
error[E0623]: lifetime mismatch
 --> src/lib.rs:2:10
  |
1 | fn only_borrow_double<T>(a: &mut &mut T) {
  |                             -----------
  |                             |
  |                             these two types are declared with different lifetimes...
2 |     *a = *a;
  |          ^^ ...but data from `a` flows into `a` here
```

Changing away from the implied lifetimes can fix the error:

```rust
fn working_double<'b, T>(a: &'b mut &'b mut T) {
    *a = *a;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure it answers my question. The best reasoning I can see in the answers is that you need to re borrow the slice. That doesn't explain why the reborrow is limited to the outer borrow's lifetime. I would like a little bit of a deeper explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to take a look at your lifetimes `'b` and `'c`:

- `&'b mut ...` means that you have a reference that is live and valid for a "time" `'b`.
- `A<'c>` means that you have an object that is live and valid for `'c`.

What you don't have is a specific relation between these two lifetimes. The only thing the compiler can deduce is that since `A<'c>` is behind a `&'b`, `'c` must outlive `'b`, i.e., whenever `'b` is valid, so is `'c`. Though, crucially, not the other way around.

As you show, the compiler requires `'b` and `'c` to be the same lifetime.
Why is this?

Let us have a look at our possibilities:

1. `'c` and `'b` have no relation: It is easy to see that without any relation, the compiler cannot guarantee anything about what is put in `A.borrow` and as such won't allow it.
2. `'c` strictly outlives `'b`, i.e., some places `'c` is valid `'b` is not:
   `a.borrow = a.borrow` becomes a reborrow of `a` using the `'b` lifetime. [This answer explains why that happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61195410/why-cant-i-assign-one-dereference-of-a-reference-of-a-reference-to-another-when#61196186). However, this means that `a` is now dependent on the `'b` lifetime, which is not valid for some of the time `a` is valid (since `a` has the lifetime `'c`). This gives the error.
3. `'b` strictly outlives `'c`: If we had this relation, it might work. The reborrow will be valid, since we get a "bigger" lifetime (`'b`) than we asked for (`'c`). However, we already have `'c: 'b` inferred by the compiler behind the scenes. Therefore, adding this lifetime means the two lifetimes become equal and we are then back where we started:

```rust
struct A<'a> {
    borrow: &'a mut u8,
}

/// We add the relation 'b: 'c
fn does_nothing<'b: 'c, 'c>(a: &'b mut A<'c>) {
    a.borrow = a.borrow;
}
```

Comment: Your explanation about `'b : 'c` is opposite of https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/trait-bounds.html

Comment: @TheThirdOne You are right, its the exact other way around. I can't find an intuitive way to remember the order. Good catch. I have corrected the answer.

Comment: This answer is still misleading. The reason the "fixed" `does_nothing` works is because the compiler *does* assume that `'c: 'b` and so when you add `'b: 'c` it concludes that `'b = 'c`. So this is just the same as `does_nothing<'b>(a: &'b mut A<'b>)`.

Comment: @trentcl why would the compiler assume `'c: 'b`? Do you maybe have a source explaining this?

Comment: @trentcl It seems you are correct. [See this code that tests it](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c36eaa7839daeb796376821180fb99e2). I'll correct the answer to reflect this. I guess the compiler looks at more than the function signature to determine relations. It doesn't do something like this with traits, so I assumed it also wouldn't do it with lifetimes.

Comment: It's part of the well-formedness requirement for `&'b mut A<'c>`; if it assumed they were completely unrelated, the signature wouldn't compile at all. The compiler doesn't have to look at more than the signature though (at least in this case). Unfortunately well-formedness isn't terribly well documented, but [here's something I wrote to show kind of how it works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4e132709dfb3df4a7bf27315b5d2651c).