# Is there a way to fill up a vector for bulk inserts with the MongoDB driver and then use it again without cloning?

Tags: mongodb, rust, bulkinsert

I want to use the [MongoDB Rust Driver](https://crates.io/crates/mongodb) to bulk-insert documents into a collection. I have a `bulk` vector that I fill and flush when reaching a given size.

My issue is that I must `.clone()` the vector when giving it to driver's API `bulk_write()`.

If I don't clone, I have a ***E0382: use after move*** error, and it seems that the API don't accept reference (***E0308: expected struct `std::vec::Vec`, found reference***).

I'm new to Rust. Is there a way to do it without cloning this big structure? (structure is not big in my sample, but is in my actual code)

There's my code:

```
// Cargo.toml extract:
//
// [dependencies]
// bson = "0.10"
// mongodb = "0.3.7"

#[macro_use(bson, doc)] extern crate bson;
extern crate mongodb;
use mongodb::coll::options::WriteModel;
use mongodb::{Client, ThreadedClient};
use mongodb::db::ThreadedDatabase;

fn main() {

    // Connect to MongoDB and select collection
    let client = Client::connect("localhost", 27017).ok().expect("Failed to initialize client.");
    let coll = client.db("test").collection("mycol");

    // Make the bulk vector
    let mut bulk = Vec::new();
    for i in 0..1000 {

        // Append a item to the bulk
        bulk.push(WriteModel::UpdateOne { filter: doc!{"_id": i},
                                          update: doc!{"$set" => {"hello" => "world"}},
                                          upsert: Some(true) });

        // Each 11 items, flush bulk
        if bulk.len() > 10 {
            println!("Upsert {} docs into collection...",bulk.len());

            // `bulk` have to be cloned here
            let result = coll.bulk_write(bulk.clone(), true); // Unoptimal: bulk cloned
            //let result = coll.bulk_write(bulk, true); // E0382: use after move
            //let result = coll.bulk_write(&bulk, true); // E0308: expected struct `std::vec::Vec`, found reference 

            // Check result
            match result.bulk_write_exception {
                Some(exception) => {
                    if exception.message.len()>0 {
                        println!("ERROR: {}",exception.message);
                    }
                }
                None => ()
            }
            bulk.clear();
        }
    }

    // Final flush
    if bulk.len() > 0 {
        println!("Upsert {} docs into collection...",bulk.len());
        let result = coll.bulk_write(bulk.clone(), true);
        match result.bulk_write_exception {
            Some(exception) => {
                if exception.message.len()>0 {
                    println!("ERROR: {}",exception.message);
                }
            }
            None => ()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27098807/3005167) solve your problem? If not, can you explain why?

Comment: Thanks, the `mem::swap()` solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

As @kazemakase pointed out in the comments, the [general solution to these kinds of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27098807/3005167) is `mem::replace()`. However, in this case, the reason we need to hang onto `bulk` is for the final case when `bulk.len() <= 10`. If we restructure the original code, we can avoid the **Use after move error** entirely:

```
// Connect to MongoDB and select collection
let client = Client::connect("localhost", 27017).ok().expect("Failed to initialize client.");
let coll = client.db("test").collection("mycol");

let ranges: Vec<_> = (0..1000).into_iter().collect();
for range in ranges[..].chunks(11) {
    let bulk: Vec<_> = 
        range.map(|i| WriteModel::UpdateOne { filter: doc!{"_id": i},
                                              update: doc!{"$set" => {"hello" => "world"}},
                                              upsert: Some(true) })
        .collect();

    println!("Upsert {} docs into collection...", bulk.len());

    let result = coll.bulk_write(bulk);
    if let Some(exception) = result.bulk_write_exception {
        if exception.message.len() > 0 {
            println!("ERROR: {}", exception.message);
        }
    }
}
```

The main change here is to use `slice::chunks()` instead of manually building the chunks into `bulk` in the main iteration loop. The other nice thing is that this removes the duplicated error handling and is more idiomatic Rust.

Comment: Also https://docs.rs/itertools/0.7.4/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.chunks

Comment: Thanks! Issue of the slice::chunk() [https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.chunks] solution is the first collect(), for example if the documents to insert are generated by parsing a 3Gb file, it could be memory costly to get them all before starting to insert. That's why I would prefer the itertools::chunks() proposed above by Shepmaster because it applies to an iterator instead of slices.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to kazemakase, I could solve my own issue by creating a new empty vector, swap both vectors and send the full one. Here's the new working code:

```
// Cargo.toml extract:
//
// [dependencies]
// bson = "0.10"
// mongodb = "0.3.7"

#[macro_use(bson, doc)] extern crate bson;
extern crate mongodb;
use mongodb::coll::options::WriteModel;
use mongodb::{Client, ThreadedClient};
use mongodb::db::ThreadedDatabase;
use std::mem;

fn main() {

    // Connect to MongoDB and select collection
    let client = Client::connect("localhost", 27017).ok().expect("Failed to initialize client.");
    let coll = client.db("test").collection("mycol");

    // Make the bulk vector
    let mut bulk = Vec::new();
    for i in 0..1000 {

        // Append a item to the bulk
        bulk.push(WriteModel::UpdateOne { filter: doc!{"_id": i},
                                          update: doc!{"$set" => {"hello" => "world"}},
                                          upsert: Some(true) });

        // Each 11 items, flush bulk
        if bulk.len() > 10 {
            println!("Upsert {} docs into collection...",bulk.len());

            let mut bulk2 = Vec::new(); // create new empty bulk
            mem::swap(&mut bulk, &mut bulk2); // bulk <-> bulk2
            let result = coll.bulk_write(bulk2, true);  // send full bulk

            //let result = coll.bulk_write(bulk.clone(), true); // Unoptimal: bulk cloned
            //let result = coll.bulk_write(bulk, true); // E0382: use after move
            //let result = coll.bulk_write(&bulk, true); // E0308: expected struct `std::vec::Vec`, found reference 

            // Check result
            match result.bulk_write_exception {
                Some(exception) => {
                    if exception.message.len()>0 {
                        println!("ERROR: {}",exception.message);
                    }
                }
                None => ()
            }
            //bulk.clear(); // bulk is now a new empty bulk, clear is unecessary
        } // Compiler will drop bulk2 (the full bulk) at this point
    }

    // Final flush
    if bulk.len() > 0 {
        println!("Upsert {} docs into collection...",bulk.len());
        let result = coll.bulk_write(bulk, true); // No clone nor swap needed here
        match result.bulk_write_exception {
            Some(exception) => {
                if exception.message.len()>0 {
                    println!("ERROR: {}",exception.message);
                }
            }
            None => ()
        }
    }
}
```