# How to assign data of a struct into self in a method?

Tags: methods, reference, rust

I am trying to modify `self` that temporarily is stored into another variable. At the last step I want to copy all the data from the variable into `self`.

```
struct A {
    x: i32,
}

impl A {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self { x: 0 }
    }

    fn change(&mut self) {
        let mut a = Self::new();
        a.x += 1;

        self = a; // How to copy data from a variable into self?
    }
}
```

I get the error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:14:16
   |
14 |         self = a; // How to copy data from a variable into self?
   |                ^
   |                |
   |                expected &mut A, found struct `A`
   |                help: consider mutably borrowing here: `&mut a`
   |
   = note: expected type `&mut A`
              found type `A`
```

I have tried `self = &a` and `self = &mut a`, it didn't work. How am I supposed to copy the data into `self` from `a` in this line?

I know that my example is not optimal because I could just write `self.x += 1`. In my complete project, I have hard calculations with `a` that include `self` itself so I need to copy in the last line strictly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to dereference `self`:

```
*self = a;
```

There's nothing unique about `self` or the fact that this is a method. The same thing is true for *any* mutable reference where you are replacing the value.

See also:

- [How can I swap in a new value for a field in a mutable reference to a structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27098694/155423)