# How to return a value in a function when Option<T> is Some(), or else exit with None when it is None?

Tags: function, rust, match, option-type

I'm trying to implement an iterator for a struct:

```
struct A {
    x: Option<String>,
    y: Option<String>,
    z: String,
    index: usize,
}

impl Iterator for A {
    type Item = String;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let result = match self.index {
            0 => /* **magic deciding thing for self.x** */,
            1 => /* **magic deciding thing for self.y** */,

            2 => String,
            _ => return None,
        };
        self.index += 1;
        Some(result)
    }
}
```

Is there any way to always increment `index`, and then exit the function if the value in `x` or `y` is `None`, otherwise unwrap `Some()` and carry on as usual? There are no default values I can return.

Comment: The [duplicates applied to your case](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8528b40a6ef5f4c0b6704621b23af286)

Comment: Do [you mean this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a206300ea9c89934ffe53f3508737ac3) or [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=942f6232cd95f6152bd27d844584e370)?

Comment: You might also want `.take()` instead of `.clone()` for `x` and `y`, although I'm not sure what you're going to do with `z`.

Comment: @trentcl in that case, [you can use `mem::take`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41370552/155423) :-)

Comment: I think [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a206300ea9c89934ffe53f3508737ac3) is exactly what I needed! Thank you so much!

Comment: Or use [combinators](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=729b52576fcdf963bfaa3cbd506bbd6f).