# How do I move bytes out of a rust String

Tags: string, memory, rust

I have a struct that contains a string.

```rust
struct Foo {
    s: String
}
```

This string gets extended with bytes that I want to pass out of Foo and give to some other code.

I can achieve this with a copy

```
other.s = self.s.clone();
self.s.clear();
```

but it jars because its clearly a waste and s might be kilobytes.

I need `Foo` to own the data, temporarily, passing pointer introduces lifetime issues I don't want to have to deal with.  So I would like to pass ownership of the underlying bytes.

I can also do this with an `s: Option<String>`  and  `s.take()` , temporarily `s` can be null but the syntax for manipulating data in an Option is nasty, and I never really want `s` to be null.

Comment: I think this [anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41370552/865874) applies to your question too.

Comment: The other answer applied to your question: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=533b5da32ea5d9549774830aecbf4066