# How to concat vector elements and store it back to vector?

Tags: data-structures, rust

I have a vector of a vector and need to concatenate the second one to the first (it's ok if the second one is dropped), i.e.

```
f([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]) => [[1,2,3,4,5,6], []]
```

or

```
f([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]) => [[1,2,3,4,5,6], [4,5,6]]
```

Both are okay.

My initial solution is:

```
fn problem() {
    let mut items = Vec::new();
    items.push(vec![1,2,3]);
    items.push(vec![4,5,6]);
    items[0].append(&mut items[1]);
}
```

But it has a compile time error due to 2 mutable borrows:

```
   |     items[0].append(&mut items[1]);
   |     -----    ------      ^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
   |     |        |
   |     |        first borrow later used by call
   |     first mutable borrow occurs here
```

I could solve it with `Box` / `Option`, but I wonder whether there are better ways to solve this?

---

My solution with `Box`:

```
fn solution_with_box() {
    let mut items = Vec::new();
    items.push(Box::new(vec![1,2,3]));
    items.push(Box::new(vec![4,5,6]));
    let mut second = items[1].clone();
    items[0].as_mut().append(second.as_mut());
}
```

My solution with `Option`:

```
fn solution_with_option() {
    let mut items = vec::new();
    items.push(some(vec![1,2,3]));
    items.push(some(vec![4,5,6]));
    let mut second = items[1].take();
    items[0].as_mut().unwrap().append(second.as_mut().unwrap());
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I swap in a new value for a field in a mutable reference to a structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27098694/how-can-i-swap-in-a-new-value-for-a-field-in-a-mutable-reference-to-a-structure)

Comment: `Vec` implements `Default`, so you can use `mem::take` as Shepmaster's answer suggests. [Here's what that might look like.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1a44dfc8d725109c2d6e7ba5f24f7cd4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clone the data of `items[1]` as follows:

```
fn main() {
    let mut items = Vec::new();
    items.push(vec![1,2,3]);
    items.push(vec![4,5,6]);
    let mut a: Vec<i32> = items[1].clone();
    &items[0].append(&mut a);
}
```

If you don't want to clone the data, you can use `mem::take` as suggested by @trentcl

```
fn main() {
    let mut items = Vec::new();
    items.push(vec![1,2,3]);
    items.push(vec![4,5,6]);
    let second = std::mem::take(&mut items[1]);
    items[0].extend(second);
    println!("{:?}", items);
}
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention: the inner vector can be large (and the concatenation happens frequently). so cloning it would take some times

Comment: @PahleviFikriAuliya Note that your solution using `Box` also clones the entire vector.

Comment: @PahleviFikriAuliya if you don't want to clone the value, you can use mem:take

Comment: @trentcl doesn't it only clone the reference to the vector?

Comment: @PahleviFikriAuliya No, a `Box` is not the same as a reference. A `Box` uniquely owns its contents, so there can't be two `Box<T>`s that point to the same `T`. Cloning the `Box` implies cloning the `T`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not fastest way of doing it but it solves your problem.

```rust
fn problem() {
    let mut items = Vec::new();
    items.push(vec![1,2,3]);
    items.push(vec![4,5,6]);

    //we can not have two mutable references in the same scope
    // items[0].append(&mut items[1]);

    // instead you can flatten vector
    let first = items.into_iter().flatten().collect(); // we consume items so its no longer available
    let items = vec![first, vec![]];

    println!("{:?}", items); // [[1,2,3,4,5,6], []]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`split_at_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut) on a slice or vector to get mutable references to non-overlapping parts that can't interfere with each other, so that you can mutate the first inner vector and the second inner vector at the same time.

```rust
let mut items = Vec::new();
items.push(vec![1,2,3]);
items.push(vec![4,5,6]);

let (contains_first, contains_second) = items.split_at_mut(1);
contains_first[0].append(&mut contains_second[0]);

dbg!(items);
```

[Rust Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2cecc3cb571b3ff9155fdcd8819d1969)

No copying or cloning occurs. Note that `contains_second[0]` corresponds to `items[1]` because the second slice `split_at_mut` returns starts indexing at wherever the split point is (here, `1`).

Answer (score 0):

*you can solve the problem in two steps:*
append the empty vector at the end
remove items[1] and append its elements to items[0]

```
fn problem() {
    let mut items = Vec::new();
    items.push(vec![1,2,3]);
    items.push(vec![4,5,6]);
    items.push(vec![0;0]);
    let v = items.remove(1);
    items[0].extend(v);
}
```